# vb.net Column value retrieval

Tags: vb.net

i am getting the value of one of the column from the table via the below code...

```
Return 

CType(oItem.Item(CType(oItem.DataRow.Table.PrimaryKey.GetValue(0), DataColumn).ColumnName), Long)
```

In **oitem** I am getting the list of values like  `Id ="123"`, `Name ="xyz"`, `Age = "25"` and so on....

From the above query I am getting the value **123** which is Id...

I want to know how to retrieve the **Age**

What changes should i make in the above code.

Please help....

Comment: You don't explain what oItem is and how do you retrieve it

Comment: oitem is an object of which class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hard to tell without knowing the type of oItem but try this

CType(oItem.Item(CType(oItem.DataRow.Table.Columns("Age"), DataColumn).ColumnName), Long)